# Assets downloaded from network when initiated from script tag

Tags: service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'm using workbox with workbox-webpack-plugin to cache some assets.
My current config is supposed to cache two files: a .js and a .css.
Both files are being cached properly, but the problem is that the browser still downloads them from the network, and I have no idea why.

Here's the workbox plugin in my webpack config that generates the service worker:

```
new GenerateSW({
  swDest: 'service-worker.js',
  importWorkboxFrom: 'local',
  chunks: ['myChunk'],
  skipWaiting: true,
  clientsClaim: true,
  ignoreUrlParametersMatching: [/.*/],
  cacheId: 'myCacheId',
}),
```

Here's the generated service worker:

```
/**
 * Welcome to your Workbox-powered service worker!
 *
 * You'll need to register this file in your web app and you should
 * disable HTTP caching for this file too.
 * See https://xxx
 *
 * The rest of the code is auto-generated. Please don't update this file
 * directly; instead, make changes to your Workbox build configuration
 * and re-run your build process.
 * See https://xxx
 */

importScripts("workbox-v3.6.3/workbox-sw.js");
workbox.setConfig({modulePathPrefix: "workbox-v3.6.3"});

importScripts(
  "precache-manifest.14645da973669ef1d2247d1863e806bd.js"
);

workbox.core.setCacheNameDetails({prefix: "myCacheId"});

workbox.skipWaiting();
workbox.clientsClaim();

/**
 * The workboxSW.precacheAndRoute() method efficiently caches and responds to
 * requests for URLs in the manifest.
 * See https://xxx
 */
self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.suppressWarnings();
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {
  "ignoreUrlParametersMatching": [/.*/]
});
```

And precache manifest:

```
self.__precacheManifest = [
  {
    "revision": "9b22d66a17276ac21d45",
    "url": "myChunk.js"
  },
  {
    "revision": "9b22d66a17276ac21d45",
    "url": "myChunk.css"
  }
];
```

The precaching actually works, but it looks like the fetch event is not intercepted by the service worker. If I try to download the files directly from the address bar in Chrome, the file is loaded correctly from the service worker. But when it's loaded from the `script` tag of my page, it's still being downloaded from the network.

Here are the request header when loaded from the script tag:

```
GET /assets/myChunk.js?1546600720154 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:5000/xxx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr-BE;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,te-IN;q=0.6,te;q=0.5
Cookie: visitor_id=f86c312d-76e2-468d-a5c5-45c47fa3bbdc
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Network DevTools panel showing the relevant traffic?

Comment: Here you go:
https://imgur.com/a/vfjr9N3

Comment: Did you check your service worker clients (DevTools / Application / your service worker)? Is your website listed there?

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTTP traffic snippet you've posted, your `<script>` tag results in a request for `/assets/myChunk.js?1546600720154`. The `1546600720154` query parameter bit is causing a mismatch when attempting to match that request against the precached URLs.

I'd suggest one of two things:

1. [Configure webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/#output-filenames) to add a content hash as part of your URLs, and use that in favor of the time-based URL parameters for cache-busting. Workbox should be able to just read those hashed URLs as-is.
2. Continue using the time-based URL query parameter for cache-busting, but configure Workbox to ignore those parameters when determining whether there's a match against the precached URLs. You can do that by using the [`ignoreUrlParametersMatching`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching#ignore_url_parameters) option. It takes an array of `RegExp`s, and something like `ignoreUrlParametersMatching: [/^\d+$/]` would be enough to tell Workbox to ignore any query parameters that consist entirely of numbers.

I'd probably go with option 1 if you could.

Comment: I'm actually already doing (2) see in the GenerateSW call:
`ignoreUrlParametersMatching: [/.*/],`

Changing the url param when accessing it directly from the address bar still loads the asset from the SW, so it seems to be configured correctly on that part.

Comment: Oops—sorry, I missed that part.